# Number of minutes until an unknown DateTime

Tags: c#

If I have a `DateTime` variable that's set to the future, and I don't know if it's set to Utc or Local time, how can I find the number of minutes until this time? Something like this:

```
DateTime futureTime;
// futureTime is set to some value...
int minutesUntilFutureTime = futureTime - DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: You could look at the `Kind` to know of it is UTC or local then just subtract

Comment: Timezones are a tricky thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOYBut IIRC internally DateTime should be using UTC or soemthing close to it (like Unix Time). Do not mix up the string representation with the actuall value of a DateTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a TimeSpan object

```
 TimeSpan untilFutureTime = futureTime - DateTime.Now;
```

TimeSpan has a property called minutes and total minutes, total minutes is what you want.

```
 int minutesUntilFutureTime = untilFutureTime.TotalMinutes;
```

doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Minutes only returns the minutes component of the TimeSpan.
So if the TimeSpan is 2 hours and 3 minutes, Minutes will return 3 and not 123

Comment: Fortunately, there's a `TotalMinutes` property that will get the full count.

Answer (score 3):

DateTime has a [Kind property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.8) that allows you to determine whether or not the time is Local or UTC.
It also can be `Unspecified` in which case I think you just have to guess because you don't have enough information.

Another option could be to use the [.ToLocalTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8) method to force your DateTime to always be expressed a Local DateTime.

```cs
DateTime futureTime;
double minutesUntilFutureTime = (futureTime.ToLocalTime() - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;
```